# How To Expose Running .NET Application Object To COM For VBA.GetObject? (Not Duplicate)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, winforms-interop

I am having *no* problems writing a .NET WinForms executable, exposing some of the classes therein to COM, and using them in Excel VBA through something like:

```
Set myVbaObj = VBA.CreateObject("MyNameSpace.MyClassName")
myVbaObj.SayHi "I hope somebody will answer this question."
```

Where my .NET class has been made COM visible thusly:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNameSpace
{

  [Guid("GUID created by Visual Studio->Tools->Create GUID")]
  public interface IMyClassName
  {
    void SayHi(string Msg);
  }

  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("Other GUID created by Visual Studio->Tools->Create GUID")]
  [ProgId("MyNameSpace.MyClassName")]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class MyClassName : IMyClassName
  {
    public MyClassName()
    {
      RegistrationServices rs;

      try
      {
        // Class constructor registers itself for COM
        rs = new RegistrationServices();
        if (!rs.RegisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
                                AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase))
        {
          throw new Exception
          ("Error registering MyClassName COM component.");
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new Exception(string.Format(
          "Error in {0} constructor:\r\n{1}",
          this.GetType().Name, ex.Message));
      }
      // End of MyClassName constructor
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public void SayHi(string Msg)
    {
      try
      {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
          "Hi from Excel: '{0}'.", Msg));
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new Exception(string.Format(
          "Error in {0}.SayHi:\r\n{1}",
          this.GetType().Name, ex.Message));
      }
      // End of SayHi()
    }
  }
}
```

However, I wanna be like Excel and expose the .exe so I can reference and interact with a *running* instance of my .NET app.  In Excel VBA, this happens through 'GetObject':

```
Set myVbaObj = VBA.GetObject( , "MyNameSpace.Application")
```

But I am stumped on getting something like that to actually work the way the following will work in Excel VBA (immediate window):

```
Set xlApp = VBA.GetObject( , "Excel.Application")
print xlApp.caption
```

**EDIT:** Put in my interface definition which was originally omitted.

Answer (score 0):

So [this guy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17490/Running-Object-Table-Provider-in-NET-consumer-in-M) had a really nice article that answered my question.  Although he goes into greater detail, the apparent minimum requirement is registering the object in the Running Objects Table (ROT).  My implementation looks something like below. I am getting an error when trying to implement the Dispose function from the article (I wanted to answer this before anybody else wasted their time).

Add this class definition (direct copy/paste from article - 'punk' is probably pointer unknown):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Ole32
{
  [DllImport("Ole32.Dll")]
  public static extern int CreateBindCtx(int reserved,
  out UCOMIBindCtx bindCtx);
  [DllImport("oleaut32.dll")]
  public static extern int RegisterActiveObject
      ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punk,
          ref Guid rclsid, uint dwFlags, out int pdwRegister);

  // End of Ole32 class definition
}
```

Make these changes to the class constructor and add the module level variable:

```
private int _DwRegister;

public MyClassName()
{
  RegistrationServices rs;

  try
  {
    // Class constructor registers itself for COM
    rs = new RegistrationServices();
    if (!rs.RegisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
                            AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase))
    {
      throw new Exception
      ("Error registering MyClassName COM component.");
    }
    Guid guid = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(SmartDesigner));
    Ole32.RegisterActiveObject(this, ref guid, 0, out _DwRegister);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(string.Format(
      "Error in {0} constructor:\r\n{1}",
      this.GetType().Name, ex.Message));
  }
  // End of MyClassName constructor
}
```

At this point, once the class is instantiated one way or another (I just created an instance in the 'Shown' event of my application's main WinForm), you should be able to access it through VBA.GetObject.